# Neural Network Assumptions in a Time series

Tags: time-series, neural-networks, autocorrelation, heteroscedasticity, prediction-interval

I was wondering whether an artificial neural network regression, like ARIMA, requires statistically insignificant residual autocorrelation -- and, if so, why?

I presume that, if I am using the ANN model to forecast prediction intervals, statistically insignificant heteroscedasticity and statistically significant residual normality are requisites. Is this correct?

Comment: I do not think ARIMA is an artificial neural network regression. It looks and works pretty differently.

Comment: Right. ARIMA is a time series model. I guess my question is: do all time series model require insignificant serial autocorrelation -- or is that specific to linear models? As for the normality / heteroskedasticity question, I presume those assumptions hold as long as I am building my intervals using Upper / Lower Bound = y_hat +/- z * SD. Is that correct?

Comment: I think a brief answer is a Yes.

Comment: Thank you my friend. Also, not to overwhelm with questions, am I essentially confined to White's heteroskedasticity test if my residuals are not normally distributed? I believe the BP test requires residual normality ... Otherwise, for building prediction intervals,I think I can circumvent the normality requirements for the residuals by fitting them to another distribution, estimating the parameters, generating random numbers using those, and then selecting the values corresponding to the desired quantiles. Sorry to bombard with questions -- and thank you for your input! :)

Comment: Yes, using quantiles of the empirical distribution of the residuals for contructing a prediction interval could be OK. Regarding White test vs. BP test, I simply don't remember. I would have to look this up somewhere, but you could do the same equally well.

Comment: @RichardHardy I respectfully disagree with regards to "I think a brief answer is a Yes." -- see my answer.

Comment: @SkanderH, thank you, I will check your answer out later in the day. By the way, my answer was to the comment, not to the original post.

Answer (score 1):

Unlike ARMA and ARIMA, there are no assumptions required whatsoever when performing time series modeling with Neural Networks. This is because Neural Networks are universal approximators, and with a deep and wide enough architecture, they can approximate any arbitrary function. Moreover, they are not based on any statistical assumptions, and are instead "brute force/mechanical" non parametric function approximators, so considerations like heteroscedasticity, non-correlated errors, stationarity, etc...don't come into play the way they would for a regression model or for ARIMA.

That being said, in practice, there is some evidence that performing some of the customary transformations, like stabilizing the variance with a power transform, detrending and/or deseasonalizing, improves the performance of various deep learning models on forecasting tasks. In my personal experience, just performing normalization (e.g. using the sklearn standardscaler or minmaxscaler) gives results that are just as good as a more complex preprocessing like a power transform, at least in the LSTM case. The time series in my use case were all short and had little or no trend at all to begin with, only seasonal patterns.

But opinions and findings differ: Rob Hyndman's [NNETAR model uses a power transform](https://otexts.com/fpp2/nnetar.html). Smyl, [in the LSTM model that won the M4 competition](https://eng.uber.com/m4-forecasting-competition/), removed both the seasonality and the trend. [Hansika Hewamalage, Christoph Bergmeir
, Kasun Bandara](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1909.00590.pdf) say that it depends: Sometimes detrending is enough, sometime removing the seasonality is necessary as well.

To reiterate, Neural Networks are universal function approximators that do not rely on any formally defined statistical/stochastic process, and hence none of the requirements of ARIMA are relevant in theory, but in practice, trying to enforce some of these requirements might give better results than just feeding the time series directly to the network.

You mention:

> I presume that, if I am using the ANN model to forecast prediction intervals, statistically insignificant heteroscedasticity and statistically significant residual normality are requisites. Is this correct?

No. As I said above, not at all. Moreover, [one neural network forecasting model at least](http://proceedings.mlr.press/v89/gasthaus19a/gasthaus19a.pdf) goes completely in the other direction and does full non-parametric density forecasts, that are based on the idea that we can't make any assumptions whatsoever on the statistical properties of our time series.

---

In response to @Richard Harris' comment on stationarity being necessary, the below forecast for the Air Passengers time series was generated using an LSTM model, where the only preprocessing was normalizing via the variance and the mean of the data set ($x^* = \frac{x-\mu_x}{\sigma_x})$. Here [is the code](https://github.com/SkanderHn/TimeSeriesTensorflow/blob/master/AirPassengersLSTMTensorFlowBetter.ipynb) - using Tensorflow. Note that this won't run on later versions (TF 2.x) and would require you to downgrade to TF 1.12 or 1.13.

[image]

Comment: Regarding your first paragraph (and related ideas later on): without some form of stationarity, no method will be able to generalize from a sample to the data generating process and new samples from it. Neural networks are no exception.

Comment: @RichardHardy I disagree. I've tried myself.

Comment: @RichardHardy see plot and link to code I posted.

Comment: Clearly, the Air Passengers data is stationary in some sense. It is trend+seasonality stationary, I guess. Try a couple of independent random walks and see how successfully a neural network predicts (out of sample) one given the other. It will fail miserably, just as any other method would.

Comment: @RichardHardy Interesting thought. Can you clarify for me though: To the best of my knowledge no time series model can predict a random walk, other than a random walk?

Comment: In a sense, a random walk is unpredictable by definition. I am not saying neural networks are worse than the competition, I am just saying they are not magic, and I think the overly positive opinion (according to my understanding of it) of them as expressed in the answer is unwarranted.

Comment: @RichardHardy apologies if my response came across as a "pro-Neural Network" editorial. I was simply stating objective facts from the latest research and my own experience about how to apply them to time series forecasting. I know they are not magic, [I've just had to explain that to someone elsewhere in this forum](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/472598/89649). But just as they are not magic, I feel that there is also something of an overreaction to them in the forecasting community, with them being dismissed out of hand with misleading or faulty arguments.